# Как создать сложное поле в Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, views

Весь интернет в примерах, где все свойства в сущностях автоматические, ни разу не видел чтобы что-то было реализовано. Но как быть, если мне, к примеру нужно сделать некое вычисляемое поле? Например текущий возраст сотрудника.

Comment: если Вам необходимо вычисляемое свойство на стороне бд то следует обратить внимание на @АлексейАлыбин, иначе, т.е. на стороне клиента то тогда смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в классе реализуете необходимое Вам свойство и ставите ему атрибут [[NotMapped]](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx)

---

Пример как бы я это сделал

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public int Age
    {
        //здесь реализуете свое вычисляемое свойство
    }
}
```

---

Для реализации того же самого при подходе *Model First* вот в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773002/5610621) рекомендуют создать частичный класс в котором создать необходимое свойство и установить ему соответствующий атрибут

Comment: При этом в структуре БД не произойдет никаких изменений?

Comment: Как сделать тоже самое при подходе model first? Где в дизайнере модели это?

Comment: @YesMan обновил ответ

Comment: @Bald, тут надо учитывать, что Ваши изменения все равно не будут видны в БД. Поэтому если требуется создать вычисляемое поле, которое видно в БД, то Ваш ответ не подходит.

Comment: @AlexKrass хорошее замечание, тут наверно следует исходить из того что действительно нужно, можно организовать и *вычисляемое* свойство на стороне бд, тогда данное свойство ничем не будет отличаться на стороне ef

Comment: @Bald Как реализовать вычисляемое свойство на стороне БД, если это нужно?

Comment: например так как показал вам @АлексейАлыбин: `ALTER TABLE user ADD Age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthday, GETDATE())` на основании данного кода в таблице будет создан столбец `Age` в котором будет отображаться разница в годах между текущим значением даты времени и значением в `Birthday`

Answer (score 4):

Для вычисляемого поля надо сделать приватный сеттер, добавить опцию `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` и в скрипте миграции прописать способ вычисления поля. Будет это выглядеть примерно так:

```
//модель
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
    public int Age {get; private set;}
}

// мапинг модели
public UserMap()
{
    HasKey( t => t.Id );
    Property( t => t.Id )
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )
        .IsRequired();
    Property( t => t.FirstName )
        .HasMaxLength( 100 )
        .IsRequired();
    Property( t => t.LastName )
        .HasMaxLength( 100 )
        .IsRequired();
    Property( t => t.Birthday )
        .IsRequired();   
    Property( t => t.Age ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed );   
}

// создание таблицы в скрипте миграции
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.User";,
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                FirstName = c.String(),
                LastName = c.String(),
                Birthday = c.DateTime()
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t =>; t.Id);
    Sql("ALTER TABLE user ADD Age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthday, GETDATE())");     
}
```

Comment: будет ли Ваш способ работать при подходе Model First?

Comment: @Bald , да этот способ будет работать при подходе Model First. Вам просто надо будет изменить сгенерированный скрипт миграции базы данных